# What do job colors mean?

Tags: pocket-planes

When taking a job, the jobs are sometimes presented in different colors. Most jobs are white, but I've discovered that green jobs mean you're awarded Bux instead of coins for completion. Now I've discovered blue jobs, but I can't tell their significance. What are all the possible job colors and what do they mean?

Answer (score 2):

Blue jobs are cargo and/or passengers for the current global event. Delivering them to the city of the event count towards completing it. Green jobs are indeed rewarded with bux, and white are regular jobs. There are also rare mystery parts, which are gold/orange, like the one in the image:

[image: Mystery part]

Comment: I just found a gold job, so your answer is not complete.

Comment: @StrixVaria Added it